# Using truecrypt with MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create an MS SQL Server database on a Truecrypt volume.  I need my system to have the following property: If the Truecrypt volume is not mounted then it is impossible to access the data in the database or the database log files.  I am doing the following to create the database:

```
CREATE DATABASE test1 CONTAINMENT=PARTIAL ON (NAME='test1_data', FILENAME='D:\SqlData') LOG ON (NAME='test1_log', FILENAME='D:\SQLDataLog');
go
```

where D: is my mounted Trucrypt volume.  This seems to work fine in that it creates the specified files and a useable database.  However, I am not confident it is actually secure.  I think it is storing data somewhere other than the D: volume.  I can do the following:

```
use test1;
go
CREATE TABLE Persons (ID int, name varchar(255));
go

INSERT INTO Persons VALUES (1, 'Jason');
go
```

Then close my db client, unmount the volume, reopen the client (sqlcmd), and do:

```
use test1;
go
SELECT * FROM Persons;
go
```

and I get the data I put in.  Obviously this means there is some storage happening outside the Truecrypt volume.  Am I doing something wrong, misunderstanding something, or is what I'm trying to do just not viable with MS SQL Server?

Comment: I would think truecrypt would complain a lot before letting you close the volume if SQL Server is holding the files open. Are you certain it was really unmounted?

Comment: @DigitalChris It complained and asked if I wanted to force unmount.  I told it to force unmount and it appears to have unmounted.  The D: volume is not visible in Truecrypt or the file explorer.

Comment: Run this to verify where your files really are `USE Test1 SELECT name, filename FROM sys.sysfiles`

Comment: Then I suspect SQL server is caching the info in memory, and never even finds out that the disk is gone. I would suggest: 1. stop sql server, 2. dismount truecrypt vol. 3. restart sql server  and see if that works.

Comment: @VladimirOselsky I was unable to execute the query you suggested after dismounting the volume.  I remounted the volume and recreated the database, at which point the sysfiles query indicated that the database was using the specified files on the D: volume.

Comment: @DigitalChris I just tried your suggestion.  Indeed, if I stop the server, dismount, and restart the server then I am unable to use test1.  I feel fairly good about this situation.  I wish there were some way to confirm that no data are being cached on disk on the C: drive, but I guess to some extent you have to just trust Microsoft when you use SQL Server.  I'd appreciate any suggestions about how to gain more confidence in this instance, however.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is insecure. Data can be automatically spilled by SQL Server to tempdb in various scenarios (e.g. during sorting or hashing) so you may end up leaking the content you wanted to protect.
I'd step away from TrueCrypt in this case and just use [Transparent Database Encryption](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx) if possible (which automatically encrypts also tempdb after first database is encrypted). Or, if you really want to use TC, also protect tempdb with TrueCrypt and make sure that nobody will force dismount the volumes. Otherwise you ask for database corruption and data loss.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the cache using `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`. Then, reads will fail. `CHECKPOINT` forces writes to disk and always writes to the log even if nothing is to be written. It will fail as well.

Note, that SQL Server also writes to tempdb and to its error log. Maybe to other places as well. Use Process Explorer to list the open file handles that sqlservr.exe has to find more places.

Still, I think the main places where user data can be spilled to is tempdb.

Endrju's suggestion of using TDE is worth investigating but I doubt it can prevent spills to tempdb. tempdb is used (among others) for temp tables, sort buffers, hash buffers, `CHECKDB` temp data.

Note, that when you unmount and remount, all existing file handles are invalidated and SQL Server will no longer be able to use the database. You have to take it offline and online. Unmounting at any time should be safe, though, because SQL Server is crash consistent. Instant power loss at any time is safe.

Comment: tempdb is automatically encrypted after you encrypt first database with TDE.

Comment: Thanks. Backups are also encrypted, so this important piece is protected as well. it's a pity it's Enterprise-only feature :(